# How to make Jenkins to use local M2 repository?

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I m running Jenkins in offline mode. While running maven project from command prompt it is working fine. But while running from Jenkins it is showing that some dependencies are missing. How to check which repository does Jenkin use to check the dependency ?

Comment: is the M2 repo available on the same server as your offline jenkins?

Comment: Yes it is available in the same server

Comment: can you please share error log

Comment: Try  mvn clean install -Dmaven.repo.local=/path/to/.m2/repository (the jenkins user needs access to this folder)